# What is the opposite of a mutation (the regular state)?

Tags: genetics, terminology, mutations

What is the term, if there is one, to describe the natural state of a gene? The one single word to describe it, just like **mutation** is the one single word do describe a deviation from that state.

Comment: If you had written *"what's the opposite of mutant"*, I'd have an answer for you. However, *mutation* and *mutant* are not synonyms.

Comment: If you brought this up and mentioned clearly that the two are not synonymous, what is it for Mutant? I'm asking for general knowledge.

Comment: I just added an answer and edited your title. Feel free to roll it back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A mutation can be both the act of changing the genetic material (the process) or the changed genetic material itself (the result of the process). You're using the second meaning. See [What is the definition of a mutation?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/43159/what-is-the-definition-of-a-mutation) for more info.

That being said, the opposite of a mutant allele is a **wild type** allele.

According to Pierce in his book *"Genetics: A Conceptual Approach"* (2012):

> The normal allele for a character is called the **wild type** because it is the allele most often found in the wild. (emphasis mine)

The same way, the opposite of a *mutant* phenotype is a *wild type* phenotype.

Besides that, you can sometimes find *"wild"* alone, without *"type"*: *wild allele*, *wild phenotype* etc...

---

Source: Pierce, B. (2012). Genetics. New York, NY: W.H. Freeman.

Comment: This is correct +1. In response to your comments above, note that many people use the term "mutation" for "mutant allele" which is a little confusing. Just type ["carry the mutation" in Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=%22carry+the+mutation%22&btnG=) to find examples. You might also want to have a look at [What is the definition of a mutation?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/43159/what-is-the-definition-of-a-mutation)

Comment: Yes, very confusing I'd say... And that annoys me. Anyway, OP just rolled back my edit, so I clarified the issue in my answer.

Comment: @Remi.b thanks for your edit, the linked answer is very didactic.