# Would a clone of myself have exactly the same development (character, appearance) as me?

Tags: dna, development

If I'd have a clone of myself (with my DNA) and I would record the development of that person, would I be able see exactly the same development as myself (same personality, appearance)? For example that at a certain time, that clone would look how I looked like when I was 8?

Comment: Appearance, personality etc. are also influenced by the environment (persons around your clone, geographic location, eating, sporting etc). So there are a lot of other factors which need to be the same. Further not only the sequence is important but also  epigenetics ( like methylation of DNA)

Answer (score 3):

No, your clone would differ from you. Actually such clones exist in humans also. Monozygotic twins are clones. They certainly look alike but they definitely differ in some respects.

Understanding why this is true require one to understand the concept of heritability from the field of quantitative genetics. You should definitely have a look at the post [Why is a heritability coefficient not an index of how "genetic" something is?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42273/why-is-a-heritability-coefficient-not-an-index-of-how-genetic-something-is). The main reason why you would differ is because our [phenotype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenotype) (personality, appearance, etc...) also depends on the environment we experience.

Comment: your come would be even more different becasue it would have a very different in utero environment, this can have a rather strong effect. You how to wonder how different monozygotic twins would be if they did not share the same womb.

Comment: @John I don't fully understand your comment due to the typos. Yes, of course, the correlation coefficient between twins depends on whether they share the same environment (again, see [Why is a heritability coefficient not an index of how "genetic" something is?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42273/why-is-a-heritability-coefficient-not-an-index-of-how-genetic-something-is)) which includes the uterine environment.

Comment: Sorry, that should say "Your clone" I was pointing out that the clone of an adult would have a drastically different in utero environment. This could lead to some surprising differences, in some organisms (not humans that we know of) it could even mean your clone is a diffrent sex. http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/dvdy.23924/full

Comment: In eutherian mammals, sex is determined by sexual chromosomes though, not so much by the uterine environment. But it is true that the uterine environment can be very influential. It is also true that many species that do not have a uterus, parental care will affect sex determinism.

Comment: I did say not in humans, I should have moved that to the end so you knew I was referring to sex specifically. Now epigenetics may affect sex in humans by modulating the gametes but that will not have an effect on your clone.

Comment: Yes, not in humans and not in any species that have a uterus I would think as all uterian mammals have sexual chromosomes to determine sex. But I might be wrong. I have not read the paper.