# Are hormone secretion variations the same for a pair of monozygotic twins?

Tags: genetics, human-genetics, endocrinology, human-physiology, twins

I have recently read a paper about how stress affects morning salivary cortisol levels in an individual. I am conducting a study on monozygotic twins and was wondering if cortisol levels would fluctuate similarly in a pair of twins, or whether cortisol and other hormones are unrelated to the genetic makeup of the twins.

Answer (score 2):

[Bartels et al. 2003](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12510008) is a review that reports an estimate of the heritability of the cortisol level of 0.62. In comparison to most traits, it is a relatively high heritability.

So, in short, the answer is "no". Cortisol level variation is lower among twins than among unrelated individuals. If the definition of heritability is a little bit unclear to you, you should have a look at [this post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/42273/why-is-a-heritability-coefficient-not-an-index-of-how-genetic-something-is).

The reaction norm of cortisol level (and other stress response) with varying stress level also seems to be heritable ([Ilsing and Hoelsboer 2006](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3181835/), [Volckaert et al. 2012](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3378454/)).

Comment: *"So, no cortisol level variation is lower among twins than among unrelated individuals"*... I believe you're missing a comma after the *no*, am I right?

Comment: Yes indeed! A comma changes everything! Thanks

Comment: No worries, already upvoted anyway!